# Предусмотреть в программе возможность завершения работы, если пользователь не активен в течении определенного времени. WPF,C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Как реализовать метод, который отслеживает активность окна WPF C#?
Задача стоит следующая, необходимо предусмотреть возможность программы отслеживать активность пользователя. Если пользователь, например, в течении двух минут не проводит никаких действий, то программа завершает работу.

Comment: Я уже не вспомню точно, но в wpf есть механизм, как определить, простаивает приложение или нет. Погуглите wpf idle inactivity timeot, наверняка что то найдете.

Comment: [Оно](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8310638/12888024)?